# How to change the owner of a file or folder?

Tags: permissions, ownership

Sometimes I use root account to create some file for normal user. But it is just for convenient. And I really hope the owner of this file should be the user I create this file for.

How can I change the file owner?  (GUI tools are better)

Comment: Do you know the `chown` command? It's a basic to change owner of files...

Comment: I did not know before. But after searching, it makes sense.

Comment: After all these years you'd think this is a duplicate question but I didn't see an original. +1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose you have a file named `abc` and user is `user1` and probably group will be `user1` then use the command:

```
sudo chown user1 abc
```

And if you want to change the `user` and `group` of file then:

```
sudo chown user1:user1 abc
```

Comment: You can do it recursively using -R.
sudo -R chown user1 abc